# Why does only 1 out of my 4 PHP inputs correctly write into the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Here is my HTML - The form is within a large table because I eventually want the data that is outputted from the database to be there.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="php/InsertMatch.php" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hero</td>
                    <td>Result</td>
                    <td>Game Mode</td>
                    <td>MMR</td>
                    <td>Diff</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Keeper of the light</td>
                    <td>Win</td>
                    <td>All Pick</td>
                    <td>3500</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input id="select_hero" type="text" name="select_hero"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="winloss">
                            <option value="win">Win</option>
                            <option value="loss">Loss</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="gamemode">
                            <option value="allpick">All Pick</option>
                            <option value="capmode">Captains Mode</option>
                            <option value="capdraft">Captains Draft</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input id="input_mmr" type="text" name="input_mmr"></td>
                    <td>N/a</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input id="submit_game" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit game">
        </form>
```

Summary of above: 4 things to be entered into the database. Two text inputs (neither work) and two dropdown boxes. The only one that works seems to be the `winloss` function. I will show the database entries below the PHP which comes now:

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="dota_site_test";
$tbl_name="matches";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

//names from form.
$hero=$_POST['select_hero'];
$winloss=$_POST['winloss'];
$gamemode=$_POST['gamemode'];
$mmr=$_POST['input_mmr'];

//data into mysql

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Hero, Result, GameMode, MMR)VALUES('$hero', '$winloss', 'gamemode', 'mmr')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//if successful, displays message

if($result){
    echo "Successful";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<a href='d2index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else{
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the above, I would assume nothing? Because I used most of it from here: http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/5.html

Here is what I get in my database from 2 entries with different inputs:

```
0 | win | gamemode | 0
0 | loss| gamemode | 0
```

Thus only the `winloss` seems to work..

Here is a picture of the database table info if needed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZIK3.jpg

EDIT: Whoops. I have added the $ symbols and now the `MMR` and `gamemode` work fine. But not the `hero` function. Any ideas?

EDIT2: Thank you for the warnings about SQL Injection attacks. I admit this code is VERY unsecure (only hosted on my PC), thus I warn anyone reading this to be aware of that. Thank you.

Comment: You missed the `$` in front of `gamemode` and `mmr` in the line `$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Hero, Result, GameMode, MMR)VALUES('$hero', '$winloss', 'gamemode', 'mmr')";`

Comment: Your primary problem is that you're still using the deprecated `mysql_` extension and make your code susceptible to trivial SQL injection attacks.
. Use `mysqli_` with prepared statements or PDO.

Comment: This code welcomes SQL injection

Comment: Don't use tutorials that show the old MySQL extension, look for tutorials that use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements and bind variables (e.g. http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/)

Comment: @Prashank I understand that this code is poor with regards to safeguarding against SQL injection. However at the moment I have been learning PHP/MYsql for 2 days. So I am mostly focussing on learning how to input elements into a database. This is all hosted only on my PC. So the only person who can SQL inject my stuff is my girlfriend if she chooses to. Which I am hoping not.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for the heads up, I will make sure to do that from now on.

Comment: @k4kuz0 - the problem with this mindset is that you're learning bad, insecure practises from the start; and you'll need to forget those and relearn good, secure practises when you do want to progress.... learning good, secure practises from the start will really benefit you as you progress as a developer

Comment: This code reads like a tutorial on dangerous PHP design.

Comment: @k4kuz0 if its on your pc only then i am pretty sure your girlfriend will not try sql injection when she has access to the database directly ;) and i agree with the above, start to learn with best stuff.

Comment: @Dave Well I can't fault you guys for being blunt!! I've had my inadequate code pointed out many times over. I thank you all for that ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than the gaping wide-open [SQL Injection Attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities, perhaps this?

```
INSERT [..snip...] VALUES('$hero', '$winloss', 'gamemode', 'mmr')"
                                                ^--no $     ^---no $
```

you're trying to insert fixed unchanging strings, instead of the variables you'd defined earlier.

Comment: Also it looks like `hero` is a numeric ID field which he's trying to put text into.

Comment: @DigitalChris that could be a problem, too.

Comment: @DigitalChris, the same applies to MMR -- int(20) field with text being inserted (once the $ is added)

Comment: Also, using a discouraged practice - mysql_....
I find it helpful to mention this each and every time I see someone with a question that specifies the use of these old relics.

Comment: Whoops. I have added the $ symbols and now the `MMR` and `gamemode` work fine. But not the `hero` function. Any ideas?

(With regards to the SQL Injection attack part, I am very new to PHP/MYSQL and I am first just trying to understand how to put things into a database. I will worry about that a bit later but thank you for alerting me to the problem!! This is only locally hosted for now.)

Comment: @k4kuz0, read the first comment. You are trying to insert text into a number field.

Comment: @AlexanderMP Oh god. That is true. Thank you for highlighting that DigitalChris. I have been sitting here for 40 minutes trying to suss this out. Onwards and upwards!

Comment: @DigitalChris Sorry I can't tag 2 people in one message so I just typed your name regularly, I gave you a shiny upvote for your troubles!

Answer (score 2):

this is maybe because you forgot to put `$` sign on the query.

it should be like this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Hero, Result, GameMode, MMR)VALUES('$hero', '$winloss', '$gamemode', '$mmr')";
```